# Under what user does the web server run on OS X SERVER Lion (10.7.5)

Tags: webserver, file-permissions, osx-server, owncloud

Trying to install OwnCloud on my hosted OS X Server 10.7.5.

When running the "web Installer", I can't get past the first step, because "Can't write to the current directory. Please fix this by giving the webserver user write access to the directory"

The problem is, I don't know what the webserver user is. Can you help me find out? I somehow screwed up the web directory permissions, and would like to fix it once and for all.

Thanks for any help you can provide, cheers

Comment: There is something like a hosted OS X server you can buy? Wow. What for?!?

Comment: Have you tried downloading the full package to your server ([owncloud 5.10](http://download.owncloud.org/community/owncloud-5.0.10.tar.bz2))?

Comment: Also, what webserver software are you running? Some webserver from Mac OS, or Apache?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses, and sorry for the newbie question. To close the loop:

@arkascha - Yep. MacMiniColo.net. Why not? Got a mini laying around, just sent it in

@nyarlathotep - Yes. Going through the install now. It turns out the documentation of Owncloud has been updated to address my specific problem, down to the specific CHOWN I need to use.
PROBLEM SOLVED

@nyarlathotep #2 - Running the standard Apache that comes with Lion, Apache 2